# Rails - Keeping Checkboxes Checked on Reload and Redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have a page where users select preferences - I want the checkboxes they select to be auto-selected when they revisit the page (after submit).

I've looked at a couple other threads here that seem to address the question, but I'm def. stuck - can someone throw some rails knowledge down on me?!

```
> <%= form_for @like do |f| %> 
> <% Category.select { |category| category.gender == 'guy' }.each do |category| %> 
> <%= check_box_tag 'category_ids[]', category.id, true %>
```

Likes Controller:

```
def create
    @like = Like.new(params[:like])
    params[:category_ids].each do |category|
      Like.create(:category_id => category, :user_id => current_user.id)
    end
    redirect_to new_preference_path
  end
```

Comment: can u paste code of controller action and form view code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a third argument to the check_box_tag like this:

```
<%= check_box_tag "category_ids[]", category.id, @like.category_ids.include?(category.id) %>
```

so the checkboxes are checked if the @like's category_ids include that category

Comment: I'm headed in the right direction - I'm getting an undefined method `category_ids` error.

Comment: Ah sry I forgot that u need the category ids from like because I asume they have a relationship right? try this, hope it works for you: <%= check_box_tag "like[category_ids][]", category.id, @like.categories.include?(category) %>